# How to compare value in 2 different array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to compare this array of object :

```
"platforms": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "KF",
            "bankAccounts": [
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "balance": -100,
                    "lendingPlatformId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 27,
                    "balance": 500,
                    "lendingPlatformId": 4
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "CC",
            "bankAccounts": [
                {
                    "id": 23,
                    "balance": 100,
                    "lendingPlatformId": 1
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "DD",
            "bankAccounts": [
                {
                    "id": 28,
                    "balance": 0,
                    "lendingPlatformId": 1
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
```

I want to compare the platform[].id and match  bankAccounts[].lendingPlatformId

for example:

bankAccounts[].id = 22, its lendingPlatformId = 3, so it need to find platform[].id = 3 and  bankAccounts[].id = 23 and lendingPlatformId = 1 ,then compare their balance's sum is equal to zero, than push to new array.

[image]

expecting result is one new array:

isEqualToZero = [true, false, true, false]

(order is matter)

I'm thinking make it new object like:

```
platofmrId = 1 :{ lendingPlatformId: 3, balance:100 }, {lendingPlatformId: 4, balance:500 }

platofmrId = 3 :{ lendingPlatformId: 1, balance:-100 }
```

but seems it can't achieve what i want

i've no idea how to do it...

please help, Thanks!

Comment: Maybe id=22 and id=23 's balance is 100(not -100) means they lended money  100 each other, and then they are equal to zero ?

Comment: yes they lend money to each other, so their balance must equal to zero, otherwise 'isEqual' = false, like id = 27 and id = 28 @YinPeng.Wei

Comment: As the same structure of Data, platform 1 lend 100 from platform3, and platform 3 lend 100 from 1; Both of them should be 100 ,not -100. 
Data of your question means 200 balance between 1 and 3, not 0.

Comment: i think i'm  saying wrong, in this data, platform 1 lend 100 to platform 3(means platform 1 -100), and platform 3 receive 100 from platform 1(platform 3 +100), so their sum should be 0,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const res=[] //to save result
platforms.forEach(platform=>{ //go through platforms
platform.bankAccounts.forEach(bank=>{ //go through platform bank account
    // to get lendingPlatform
    const lendPlatform=platforms.find(p=>p.id==bank.lendingPlatformId);
    //add the balance and compare 
    if((lendPlatform.bankAccounts[0].balance+bank.balance)==0)
        res.push(true) // if combined balance is zero
    else
        res.push(false) 
})})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: this works! but i got another question, i write down below please help :)

Comment: @user19304185 where is your question i can't find

Comment: sorry i already solve it, thanks to your help! you save my day:)

Comment: @user19304185 if you are a native English speaker please get in touch with me on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/vmmoorthi25)

I want to speak English fluently

Comment: nah im not a native English speaker, sorry i can't help you :(

Answer (score 0):

```
const platforms = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "KF",
      "bankAccounts": [
          {
              "id": 22,
              "balance": -100,
              "lendingPlatformId": 3
          },
          {
              "id": 27,
              "balance": 500,
              "lendingPlatformId": 4
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "CC",
      "bankAccounts": [
          {
              "id": 23,
              "balance": 100,
              "lendingPlatformId": 1
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "DD",
      "bankAccounts": [
          {
              "id": 28,
              "balance": 0,
              "lendingPlatformId": 1
          }
      ]
  }
];
const emptyArrayInit = Array.from(new Array(4), ()=>[0,0,0,0])
platforms.forEach(platform=>{
  const {id, bankAccounts}=platform;
  const index = id-1;
  bankAccounts.forEach(bankAccount=>{
    const {balance,lendingPlatformId  } =bankAccount;
    const lendingPlatformIdIndex = lendingPlatformId-1;
    if(balance>0){
      emptyArrayInit[index][lendingPlatformIdIndex] += balance;
    }else{
      emptyArrayInit[lendingPlatformIdIndex][index] += balance
    }
  })
})
console.log(emptyArrayInit,'emptyArrayInit');
```

/// [ [ 0, 0, 0, 500 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]

it's simple to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const res=[] //to save result
platforms.map(platform=>{ //first loop
platform.bankAccounts.map(bank=>{ // inner loop bankaccounts
    // to get lendingPlatforms
    const lendPlatforms=platforms.find(p=>p.id==bank.lendingPlatformId);
    //compare balance
    if((lendPlatforms.bankAccounts[0].balance+bank.balance)==0)
        res.push(true) // if combined balance is equal to zero
    else
        res.push(false) 
})})
console.log(res)
```